# asp deploying a website on a server

Tags: asp.net

I am using visual web developer express and when I build the website on localhost, everything is fine. But when I try to deploy it on a server O get many errors like:

```
line 18:

Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as
allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.
This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured
as an application in IIS.

Source Error: 

Line 16: <customErrors mode="Off"/>
Line 17: 
Line 18:       <profile enabled="true">
Line 19:        <!--<anonymousIdentification enabled="true"/--> 
Line 20:         <properties>
```

When I take this part off I get an error on line 3:

```
Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Source Error: 

    Line 1:  <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"   CodeFile="MasterPage.master.cs"           Inherits="MasterPage" %>
    Line 2:  
    Line 3:  <%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagprefix="asp" %>
    Line 4:  
    Line 5:  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0    Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 

Source File: /zimmer/MasterPage.master    Line: 3 

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit' could not be loaded.

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure in your publish settings that you are copying all files in the project folder, not the minimum required for the site. I had the same problem, and that fixed it.

Comment: i'm in the express version and  when i'm deploying i usually transfer the files by ftp or something like that. how do i publish in your way?

Comment: Ah I see. I don't have experience with express, but in the project properties there is a page called "Publish settings", which is what I am referring to. From what I heard though, the express version is much more limited in terms of how you can publish.